# How to compare lists of tuple while considering the reverse order of tuple?

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples, `a` and `b`. and I want to extract the tuple from `a` if the tuple is in `b` too.

The question is how to extract the tuples while considering the reverse order of elements in it?

For example,

```
a = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 5), (6, 2), (8, 1), (9, 8)]
b = [(1, 0), (8, 1), (5, 3)]
```

in this case, the expected output is `(0,1), (8,1), (3,5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert each tuple into a set:

```
a_sets = [set(item_a) for item_a in a]
b_sets = [set(item_b) for item_b in b]
```

Then do a list comprehension where you find the index in `a_sets` of each `b_set`, then use this to index into your original list of tuples `a`:

```
[a[a_sets.index(b_set)] for b_set in b_sets]
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (8, 1), (3, 5)]
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work, but it needs some optimization

```
a = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 5), (6, 2), (8, 1), (9, 8)]
b = [(1, 0), (8, 1), (5, 3)]

def reverseTuple(lstOfTuple):
      
    return [tuple(reversed(tup)) for tup in lstOfTuple]
              
print(reverseTuple(b))
reverse_b=reverseTuple(b)

for t in a:
    if t in b or t in reverse_b:
        print(t)
```